# How can I make ack search through a list of files listed in a text file?

Tags: file, search, grep, ack

I have foo.txt that contains a list of file names, delimited by newline. What I want to do is to use ack to search through the files listed in the foo.txt. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xargs -0 -n 1 grep search-string < foo.txt 

# -0 to handle filenames with spaces
# -n 1 means process a single file at a time
```

Answer (score 3):

With ack 2.0 and the new `-x` option, you can do this

```
cat foo.txt | ack -x search-string
```

Comment: After posting my answer I tried yours @Andy and both work the same, I think yours is actually correct based on the docs and shorter.  But worth knowing that both options can be used this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
$ ack foo file
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Pipe it through to the files from list:</strike>

<strike>`cat listoffiles.txt | ack -i searchstring --files-from=-`</strike>

Following Andy's comment below, after testing to make sure it does work, the best answer is actually:

`ack -i searchstring --files-from=listoffiles.txt`

Comment: If you're going to do that, might as well do `ack -i searchstring --files-from=listoffiles.txt`.